# How to transform from decimal to int from it own class?

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization, json-serialization, jsonconvert

I have a class with json properties and I would like it to receive an integer which is the number of zeros that should be multiplied only for the decimal properties.

2 = multiply by 100
3 = multiply by 1000
etc

...

```
[JsonProperty("max_total_txn_value")]
        public decimal MaxTotalTxnValue
        {
            //example: multiplying to 2 (2 zeros)
            get { return maxTotalTxnValue / 100; }
            set { maxTotalTxnValue = value * 100; }
        }
```

...

...

```
[JsonConstructor]
{
//some code mabe here
}
```

...

Example:

if I pass 3 (int)

12.00 (value decimal)

12.00 x 1000(3 zeros)

Result: 12000

Comment: `private int powerOfTen = int.Parse(someIntegerValueFromJsonDeserialization); maxTotalTxnValue = MaxTotalTxnValue * Math.Pow(10, powerOfTen)` ??

Comment: I was also going to say just use Pow. (Power Of) as 10^1 is 10, 10^2 is 100, 10^3 = 1000 etc. @Ingenioushax you should expand that as an Answer!

Comment: But how can I use inside the class and not outside my friends?

Answer (score -1):

To use in your class, just use it as you would any other property.

```
public int PowerOfTenFromJsonDeserialization { get; set; }

public decimal MaxTotalTxnValue => initialValue * Math.Pow(10, int.Parse(PowerOfTenFromJsonDeserialization));
```

I can't really expand much since I don't know what your class looks like, or your end goal, but I do know the above would work for your general approach. Just need to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, I'm going to try it!